# Expected value of max of a Stochastic process

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mean, expected-value, stochastic-processes

Given the Stochastic process

$$X(t) \begin{cases}
A, 0\leq t < \frac{1}{2}\\
B, t \ge \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

With $A \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $B \sim \mathcal{N}(1, 1)$.

I'm asked to find: $\mathit{E}[max_{0<t<1} X(t)]$

How can that expected value be calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via law of iterated expectations, it's equal to $$\mathbb E[\max_{0<t<1} X(t)]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\max_{0<t<1}X(t)|A,B]]=\mathbb E[\max (A,B)]$$, which you can use the formula found in Equation (11) of this [paper](https://www.gwern.net/docs/conscientiousness/2008-nadarajah.pdf). Note that the answer involves the CDF function $\Phi(t)$ of standard normal RV.

Comment: the $\rho$ in the equation of the paper stands for Pearson's correlation coefficient?

Comment: Yes, if independent it’ll be zero